GCC won’t work properly (a conflict with FreePascal)

I’ve installed MinGW and set the PATH, but GCC doesn’t see the included files like stdio.h. I’ve typed where gcc and found out that FreePascal comes with GCC. Apparently my PC is using GCC that comes with it, even though it’s not set in the PATH and I don’t know how FreePascal’s GCC managed to become the default option. However, I can’t delete FreePascal for now.
I’ve tried moving MinGW over to FreePascal’s directory but that didn’t help either. gcc -v says:
#include "..." search starts here:
End of search list.

And then it adds:
The following default directories have been omitted from the search path:
/gcc-2.95/lib/gcc-lib/i386-mingw32/2.95/../../../../include/g++-3
/gcc-2.95/lib/gcc-lib/i386-mingw32/2.95/../../../../include
/gcc-2.95/lib/gcc-lib/i386-mingw32/2.95/../../../../i386-mingw32/include
/gcc-2.95/lib/gcc-lib/i386-mingw32/2.95/include
/usr/local/i386-mingw32/include
End of omitted list.
empty.c:1: No include path in which to find stdio.h

I don’t have these default directories anywhere, so it’s fine that they’re omitted, I guess. But the end result is still that the PATH is ignored.
Any ideas? Can I fix this mess without uninstalling FreePascal?
I’ve asked this question in the FreePascal forums too.

Start by getting a current version of MinGW. Preferably MinGW-w64, supposing that you're in fact on 64-bit Windows.  GCC 2.95 is more than 20 years old.  Any recent MinGW will have a much newer GCC.

The PATH is not used to find includes. You say you've installed MinGW, but it's obviously not properly installed.

I don't think Mingw32 has been maintained in ages. Mingw64 isn't maintained either, all official download links are dead since many years.

@Lundin mingw-w64 is still maintained, there was a release not long ago. See here.

@ssbssa That's the source, not the linked binaries. They don't provide built executables since many years. And then people wonder why everyone and their mother is asking about corrupt installations trying to build it themselves.

@Lundin Well, gcc also only provides the source. But I do agree with you that it's not obvious where to get a build. They could e.g. here move up the native windows builds to the top.

Free Pascal does not come with GCC, however it packages windres, which requires gcc for preprocessing. The gcc binary in the FPC distribution is a stub that can do the minimal preprocessing required for windres.
The solution is simple, if you want to use FPC, make sure the FPC paths are active, and if you want to use mingw, make sure the mingw/msys paths are active. I remove all paths from the OS PATH list, and use a batchfile like below to switch to FPC, and analogues for other compilers.
@echo off

Rem we save oldpath only once, so we can always revert to it.

if "%OLDPATH%" neq "" goto :nosave
set OLDPATH=%PATH%
:nosave 
PATH c:\fpc\3.2.2\bin\i386-win32;%OLDPATH%


It turned out that all I had to do was remove "gcc.exe" from FreePascal's directory. Or rather I merely renamed it to "_gcc.exe" in case I need it later. And now everything works as it should! "Where gcc" points to "C:\Mingw\bin" and the compiler doesn't complain about any missing libraries.

(1) It might break windres. (2) it is not supported to have gcc directories in the PATH when utilizing Lazarus. There are many other forms of crosstalk.
